# Confirm Message Box asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to store Data to Database after the confirmation button if you click Yes  the data will be save to database if cancel nothing will happen.

Here's the code

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(
    this.GetType(), 
    "ConfirmBox", 
    "if(confirm('Are you sure?') == true){window.location='../MyReservation.aspx';};", 
     true);
```

it only directs to another page but does not save the data to database.

Thanks in advance to those will answer my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting `window.location` just loads a new page.

I assume you have a form with the data to save, use jQuery to [submit](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) that form: `$('#myForm').submit()` instead of setting `window.location`.

Answer (score 0):

Store the data in session state, and in the Load method of MyReservation.aspx, retrieve it from session and store in database. Transfer to new page instead of loading a new window.